# how to allign spinner equal in width of edittext

Tags: android, spinner

how do i align `spinner` to show equal in width in all screen?  in my code `spinner` show different width in different screen what do i do?  i have given fixed length

```
 android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
```

in `edittext` and `spinner` but `spinner` show diffrent width in diffrent screen how do i fix this issue? i this is my image of screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7lD.jpg
and below is my full source code of screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="6" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/agappbg" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMobileNo"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/MobileNo"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPinNo"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/PinNo"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/lgnspinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:prompt="@string/network_prompt" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton_small"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: image link is broken plz recheck it

Comment: http://imgur.com/RtWNgNI              chk this

Comment: is not broke i just give half screen image

Comment: if you really want a view to be fixed size in all screens(I think there is no point) you should give its layout_width property with px unit. ex/ `android:layout_width = "120px"`

Comment: if i give 120 fixed is not same in all screens in small size device is compress

Comment: You should check the following attributes android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: use a `RelativeLayout`instead of `LinearLayout` and for your `Spinner` add these attributes : `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idOfYourEditText"` and `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/idOfYourEditText"`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did code right. It just seem like its not same size with EditText box because you used default background in spinner.

If you changed its background color or image like

```
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

And you can change its background image

```
android:background="@drawable/spinnerDropDownBackground"
```

And make sure image is 9 path So that it will not starched in big screen

[How to create 9 patch for spinner ?](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/)

you will find that you did code right.

And if you want to use default background you have to change your code

```
android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
```

Hope this will help

Comment: if i give android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"   is not same in diffrent sceen sizes

Comment: if i give any color to spinner is not show right dropdown arrow

Comment: you want to it to same as size EditText box or fix size in all screen ?

Comment: yes if i change spinner color is work fine but not show spinner dropdown arrow but if i use default spiner is not fixed in all screens

Comment: can you answer my last comment so that I can help you

Comment: yes i want same spiner and edittext in all screens "chirag Saga"

Comment: @hayyaanam : but snapshot is not visible plz place right link

Comment: you can do this by changing you background image of spinner as default spinner image has padding.

Comment: i just paste half snapshot

Comment: how? padding give example MR shirag

Comment: this is ur answer chirag?   android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"

Comment: is not helping bcoz edittextview margin lefta nfd right is 45dp so diffrentr screen is show diffrent sizes of both of them

Comment: Simple so you have to use same margine and custom background image.

Comment: if i use same margine edittext and spinner sho diffrnet screen size in diffrent screens this is a iissue

Comment: How much size you want of EditText and Spinner I will give you code ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not your fault, default background of `Spinner` has this kind of image (transparent padding around it). You can see yourself by setting `android:background="#ffffff"` on `Spinner`, doing this will remove padding from `Spinner`'s sides and your problem will solve but you will loose `Spinner` arrow. I suggest you to create your own `drawable` for `Spinner` (because you are changing backgrounds of other `View`) otherwise default background is different for different OS versions and your implementation will seem broke.

Also you are using so many `LinerLayout`s for this simple layout. Consider this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMobileNo"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="MobileNo"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPinNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Pin no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/lgnspinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adjust your references again, in case you copy paste my code.

Comment: I suggest you to generate your theme from the following site and then use it and adjust your layout. Once adjusted, it wont break again because your `background`s will be same for different OS versions. http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Of course you will loose arrow because you are no longer using background with arrow, instead now you are using simple color value. That's why I commented above and suggested you to create your own `Spinner` background which has arrow. This way your `Spinner` won't change shapes on different Android OS versions.